# Custom content using in_category

Tags: php, categories, permalinks

How do I display a custom content using the `in_category` though using the parent category as a parameter and just selecting the subcategory on that category.

On my post I didn't select the parent category so that it displays the permalink like `/%category%/%postname%/` if I select the parent and the subcategory it will not show the subcategory on the permalinks which is required. if this is possible by just manipulating the permalink in the general settings it will also do the job.

Category

- Subcategory 1
- Subcategory 2
- Subcategory 3

**CODE:**

```
   <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <article>
            <section>
                <?php if (in_category('category')) { ?>     
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </section>
        </article> 
    <?php endwhile; ?>          
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in_category()` accepts an array of categories to check against. So if you can get a list of all child categories for the parent category you want to check you can use that to see if your post is in any of those.

You can do this by using `get_categories()` and specifying the `parent`. This will get all categories who are direct children of the given category. If you also specify `fields` as `ids` you can just get their IDs, which will work better for `in_category()`:

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'parent' => 123,
    'fields' => 'ids',
) );

if ( in_category( $categories ) ) : ?>
    // Content here
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you only have the slug of the parent category, you'll need to use `get_term_by()` to get the ID for use as the parent argument:

```
<?php
$parent = get_term_by( 'slug', 'category-slug', 'category' );

$categories = get_categories( array(
    'parent' => $parent->term_id,
    'fields' => 'ids',
) );

if ( in_category( $categories ) ) : ?>
    // Content here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: is it possible to just get the parent category of the current category of the post and set it in the argument? For the second code do i need replace the arrays inside the get_term_by?

Comment: In the second piece of code replace `category-slug` with the slug of your category. The 3rd argument needs to literally be `'category'`.

Comment: Regarding your first question, why? You would just be checking "Am I in a category that is a child of its parent?". It would always be true.